# Can I mention a group of users on a Salesforce Chatter post?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-chatter

The case I'm trying to solve is the following: I'm working with Service Cloud Enterprise. I'm a support agent and I'm assigned a new case. Cases are public read/write by OWD, and I want all members of a group of users to take a look at the case in case they can help me out.

The group could be implemented as a queue a public group, or a chatter group, or some other kind of group. The thing is I don't know who the members of that group are (or at least I shouldn't need to know. I just want anyone on the group to get the message).

I want to be able to make a chatter post for that case and mention the group of users, so that they get this post on their feed and they can go check the case and comment on it to help me out.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't @mention a group. I'd think the best approach would be to post to the group about the case (and perhaps include a link to the case)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I feared. Do you know if I can post on a chatter group I don't belong to?

Comment: You need to be a member of the group to post.

Comment: Mmm, that won't fit the workflow I was trying to achieve. Thanks anyway. I'll mark you answer as best.

Answer (score 1):

This was raised as an idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Ku1gAAC

and should be availble as of the winter 14 release.

Comment: Still not available on Chatter Desktop however.